# 'DecisionTreeClassificationModel' object has no attribute 'stages'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

```
tree = dtModel.stages[-1]
print(tree) #visualize the decision tree model
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeClassificationModel' object has no
> attribute 'stages'

[image]

Please click the picture link to see more details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stages are used for pipeline models, if you fit your model using pipeline you can call `model.stages`.

[Here is one example](https://dipaweshpawar.medium.com/decoding-decision-tree-in-pyspark-bdd98dcd1ddf#:%7E:text=model%20%3D%20pipeline.fit(df)).

For normal decision tree models you should just call `model.toDebugString`

Hope this answers your question.